# App works perfect on simulator, after upload to AppStore - pods not found

Tags: ios

I am developing VPN App based on https://github.com/keeshux/tunnelkit. App works perfect if i run it from macbook to simulator / real device. But as soon as i upload it to TestFlight, all users receiving crash with message: libssl not found. I suspect POD's are not uploading or i am doing something wrong.

I tryed to include all from schemes, tryed to reupload many times, but still no luck.
Also i connected Fabric, but Fabric doesn't show anythink.

Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>b8fa726b2c0020a71ba37c2ead24dd6a3deec842</string>
            <key>Kits</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>KitInfo</key>
                    <dict/>
                    <key>KitName</key>
                    <string>Crashlytics</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Openchan</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.5</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>exo2_semibold.ttf</string>
        <string>exo2_medium.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Try running you app on your device in release mode.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma same issue, works perfect in release mode with simulator

Comment: I am getting this crash Library not loaded: openssl.dylib